# Replacing commands with a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, command, debian

````
#!/bin/bash
```
download()
{
    local url=$1
    echo -n "    "
    wget -nc --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
    sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
    echo " DONE"
}
```
file="adaway.org.txt"
echo -n "Downloading $file:"
download "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EnergizedProtection/block/master/assets/active/filter/$file"
````

This is still rough but working. I just wanted to make some variables to shorten the bottom and just have my bash read from the cat file.

Comment: You don't need grep and/or sed when you're using awk. `grep --line-buffered "%" | \
    sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"` can be just `awk -v b='\b\b\b\b' '/%/{gsub(/./,""); printf "%s%4s",b,$2} END{print b}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but it sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat a.txt
http://google.com/foo
http://yahoo.com/stuff/bar

$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

input="$1"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    path="${line%/*}"
    file="${line##*/}"
    printf '\nline="%s"\n' "$line"
    printf 'path="%s"\n' "$path"
    printf 'file="%s"\n' "$file"
    echo download "${path}/${file}"
done < "$input"

$ ./tst.sh a.txt

line="http://google.com/foo"
path="http://google.com"
file="foo"
download http://google.com/foo

line="http://yahoo.com/stuff/bar"
path="http://yahoo.com/stuff"
file="bar"
download http://yahoo.com/stuff/bar
```

If not then please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: download()
{
    local url=$1
    echo -n "    "
    wget -nc --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
        sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
    echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
    echo " DONE"
}  This was the first part of what I added. I have been adding the last three manually lines manually but trying to find a way to make a variable in another file instead of having to add each time I add one.  Sorry if I didn't clarify enough. I'm totally new to this so I kind of botched the lines.  Sorry

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#download()
#{
#    local url=$1
#    echo -n "    "
#    wget -nc --progress=dot $url 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "%" | \
#        sed -u -e "s,\.,,g" | awk '{printf("\b\b\b\b%4s", $2)}'
#    echo -ne "\b\b\b\b"
#    echo " DONE"
#}

#file="adaway.org.txt"
#echo -n "Downloading $file:"
#download "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EnergizedProtection/block/master/assets/active/filter/$file"  Minus the # Was trying to get it into a format.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to say in those comments, I'm sorry but I don't understand it. Did you have feedback or a question about my answer? If you're trying to clarify your question then edit your question, don't try to put formatted text (e.g. code) or any explanations in comments - everything we need to know should be clearly laid out in your question.